# How do I inflate a shape to draw on a Canvas?

Tags: android, shapes, android-canvas

I have a shape stored in an xml file in my drawables directory.  I'd like to use it in my Canvas (I know I can define the shape in code, but I'm trying to figure out how to implement it the more "Androidy" way).

I'm at a loss as to the syntax for getting the shape out to the Canvas. Should I be trying to transform it into a Shape or a Drawable? Does it need a Matrix? A Paint? etc.

I don't need a lot of details, just point me in the right direction :)

Thanks.

[edit]
my Android XML shape looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#583010"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3px" android:bottomLeftRadius="3px"
android:topLeftRadius="3px" android:topRightRadius="3px"/>
</shape>
```

I'm assuming there must be some way to get that inflated, no?
[/edit]

Comment: you should use vectors instead of arrays if your thinking in this area. Vectors are more flexible with change.

Comment: @John, I didn't say anything about Arrays. I'm using a Shape defined in XML. What are you referring to?

Comment: +1 Sorry first thing that came to mind from "Matrix" was arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's call your file 'res/drawable/my_shape.xml'.  The following lines of code will inflate my_shape.xml from XML and draw its contents onto a Canvas.  The ImageView is used to prove that this works.

```
Drawable shape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_shape);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( shape.getIntrinsicWidth(), shape.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888 );
Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bitmap );
shape.setBounds( 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() );
shape.draw( canvas );

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
```

Make sure these lines of code are executed after setContentView in your onCreate.

To eliminate as much confusion as possible, this is a functional sample of my_shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="#DDAAAFFF" />

    <size
        android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#AAAAAA" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defined how? Something like SVG? You'll need to write your own parser and translate shape/spaths to calls to `Canvas.drawPath()/Rect()`, etc. You can write a custom view that knows how to draw itself, etc. Either way, someone has to write the code for it. Inflating is just parsing XML and creating an object graph.

Comment: No no... I have an Android Shape in XML... (I edited my question with the details)... Isn't there a way to just inflate that into an Android Object at run time?

Comment: Oh, I see. An XML shape _is_ a drawable. So if you put in /res/drawable you can refer to it in the usual way: `R.drawable.my_shape`.

Comment: that's just it, I have it in my res/drawable folder but I've tried *everything "usual" and it's not working... maybe I was just doing it too late at night, I'll try again, but if you want to post what you think will work, I'll gladly give you the check mark, if you're right :)

Comment: You might want to show what you've tried, someone might have an idea. I've never had to draw a shape on a canvas, but other than that it works as expected (as a background image, etc.)